# Transparent user images

Tags: feature-request, user-accounts, profile-picture

I uploaded an image for my Stack Overflow account and it had a transparent background.  Now it has a black background.  Is it possible to have Stack Overflow default to a white background instead of a black background?

Comment: You could edit it and add a white background yourself... Stack Exchange uses Imgur to upload images, so it's up to Imgur what color background you end up with.

Comment: Sounds good. I'll go ask them to default to white :)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the background from a transparent gif becomes grey:

[image: Screenshot]

[image: Avatar]

If you need the transparency, it works for me in Q&A posts using imgur. Is it a gif or a png?

Comment: The original image should always retain transparency. It's the automatically resized images that will have a background (Imgur reformats them to change the size).